# Get channel data about user at Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I make a bot at Microsoft Bot Framework on c#. I am trying to get Telegram data that sent to my bot. When I worked with Telegram bot API directly, I can see data about user like:

```
{
  "update_id": 1111111,
  "message": {
    "message_id": 111111,
    "from": {
      "id": 1111111,
      "is_bot": "False",
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Dillon",
      "language_code": "en-EN"
    },
    "chat": {
      "id": 111111111,
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Dillon",
      "type": "private"
    },
    "date": 1111111,
    "text": "Hello"
  }
}
```

I grab first_name from this json and my bot sends the message like:

```
- Whould you like to use John as the name?
```

I need to do the same at Microsoft Bot Framework preferably with all channels where this is possiable. I found information about state data in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state), but there is nothing about my issue. They advise me to ask user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `channelData.from.first_name`. Note that this will only work when the user has actually set their name in their profile in Telegram.  Here is a workign example.

```
    var message = await result as Activity;
    string data = message.ChannelData.ToString();
    TelegramData myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TelegramData>(data);
    var fname = myClass.message.from.first_name;
```

Created these classes with edit>paste special>paste JSON as classes:

```
public class TelegramData
{
    public int update_id { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public Chat chat { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class From
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool is_bot { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string language_code { get; set; }
}

public class Chat
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "channelData" doesn't exist in the curent context

Comment: Where are you trying to access this?  in the messages controller?

Comment: No, not in the message controller, I am trying to access in the dialog(IDialog<object>).