# Bot Framework c# without Azure Connection to Telegram

Tags: c#, botframework, telegram, telegram-webhook

I am Testing the deployment of MS Bot framework application without azure on my own host

**the concept is:**

1. the bot is a mvc webapp and can be deployed anywhere
2. our host has an SSL certificate and a vaild endpoint(https://example.com/api/messages)

My issue is with the Activity Connector as its'nt accepting api calls form telegram as follows:

```
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)<---
    {
        if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

- the **activity** is always null on API call from telegram
- here is the webhook i am using:

  https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:ABC../setWebhook?url=https://example.com/api/messages
- what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

That's because telegram doesn't send the activity of the same type as expected by bot framework.
You may try to use `activity.Properties` where the json data from telegram are sent. And then deserialize it to custom models. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48232826/10901080))

But it's not a good solution as for me.